# Component Property not showing up in Inspector Mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I am going through some coding tutorials but I've been stuck on this for ages.

The program doesn't work because I didn't select a font for the highscoretable.

In the tutorial, it says to change it in inspector mode as such:
[image]

However, in my unity there is no option to select the font.

[image]

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I just can't seem to get it up and my entire program doesn't work because of it

Update, restarted Unity and got this Error:
[image]

Comment: Fix the errors in the script

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a public reference to the font in your script in order to get the reference in the inspector

```
public class PlaceTowers : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Font font;

}
```

adding something like that to your script should do the job

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but got nothing. I restarted Unity and I got this error:

Comment: I deleted the file and re-copied the code with the public variable and still nothing

Comment: Can you edit your post with your script so I can have a look at it?

Comment: Especially as the screen shot clearly says its not loaded the current version of the script because there are errors